# jrepl.bat: can't seem to get syntax correct

Tags: batch-file, search, replace, jrepl

During the course of a batch file, a path like the following is stored in `temp.txt`:

```
c:\folder1\folder2\.
```

The period at the end is just because the path is generated from a `for /r %%a in (.)` statement. I try to get rid of this using the world famous [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) search and replace batch file, escaping the backslash with a double-backslash:

```
type temp.txt|jrepl "\\." "" >temp2.txt
```

Only problem is that this produces strange results because the search string is interpreted as a regular expression instead of a literal string.  So then I tried this as instructed by the jrepl documentation:

```
type temp.txt|jrepl "\\." "" /l >temp2.txt
```

...but then for some reason nothing changes.  The trailing `\.` at the end of the URL unfortunately remains intact.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I assume an X-Y problem. I'm interested in your full  `for` command because I'm not able to replicate your output with your snippet.

Comment: I agree with the above. It is likely that the trailing `\.` can be prevented in the first instance. Also, even if it couldn't be avoided, there are ways of doing this without having to resort to a third party hybrid script with a very large list of possible options.

Comment: You wouldn't have that output to fix fortismo, if you instead replaced `(.)` with `(*)`.

Comment: Sorry, the original 'for' command wasn't `/f`, it was `/r`.  Here is the command:  `for /r %%f in (.) do call :RPWP "%%f"`  One of my original solutions was to replace the `(.)` with `(*)`, but it didn't work - can't remember why.  I just remember it made things way worse.  I am 100% sure that my entire 1000 line batch file is just littered with inefficiencies and duct tape absurdities, but what can I say, I'm just an amateur (not a computer professional) who barely has time to scratch and claw at what I can.

Comment: Also @Compo I am totally with you.  I always want the simplest solution I can find that won't die (like a `srch.exe` file I had 20 years ago), and generally searching/replacing text from the command line has proven to be something that's way harder to find solutions to than I thought. Originally I used `repl`, then I figured I had to switch to `jrepl` because I've seen a bunch of people asking questions about `repl` and they're just told `repl` has been abandoned and replaced with `jrepl`. This is the only solution I've found that doesn't rely on putting eggs into an untrustworthy .exe basket.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why replacing the incorrect `.` with the correct `*` would not work. Please try these three commands in a batch file and take a look at their output, 1. ```@For /R "%LocalAppData%" /D %%G In (.) Do @Echo %%G``` 2. ```@For /R "%LocalAppData%" /D %%G In (.) Do @Echo %%~fG``` 3. ```@For /R "%LocalAppData%" /D %%G In (*) Do @Echo %%G```. Then report back any differences in the results, or any errors which occur.

Comment: @Compo, I finally got around to replacing all of my `(.)` references with `(*)` and found out the hard way why this is not a good solution.  When you use `(*)`, the recursive search omits the current directory, while `(.)` begins with the current directory.  In my recursive search, I need the current directory to be included.

Comment: You didn't say that was a requirement

Comment: Yes, I also said that I tried `*` early on and couldn't remember why it didn't work.  I didn't know that excluding the current folder in a recursive search was even in the realm of possibility, without going out of one's way with special code to exclude it.   So, I'm not sure how I should have known to include that specification as a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered my own question.  Once I added the /l option, I no longer needed to escape the backslash, so what works ends up being:

```
type temp.txt|jrepl "\." "" /l >temp2.txt
```

Almost deleted this whole question but figured maybe 2 more people might encounter this issue over the next 750 years, so what the heck.